# Where in America did James Macpherson travel?

Tags: british-empire, 18th-century, colonial-america, north-america, florida

I'm looking into [James Macpherson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/James_Macpherson), the 18th century Scottish writer, and I can't find much. I know that in 1764 he took a job as secretary to the colonial governor, [George Johnstone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/George_Johnstone_(Royal_Navy_officer)), also a Scott, in Pensacola (?[West Florida](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/West_Florida)?). But Macpherson quickly got into an argument with Johnstone, as he did with many people around that time in his life. Macpherson left Pensacola and traveled through North America before returning to Britain two years after he left.

Macpherson's Wikipedia entry refers to the book *The life and letters of James Macpherson, containing a particular account of his famous quarrel with Dr. Johnson*. [That book is available online for free.](https://archive.org/details/lifeandlettersof00saunuoft) As I write this, I'm close to being done with reading it. The author almost completely skips over Macpherson's trip to America, which is one of the reasons why I ask the question here. I can't find any other detailed documentation about Macpherson.

Does anyone know precisely what Macpherson's argument with Johnstone was about?

More importantly: where in America did Macpherson go during his journey?

And if there is a book or document (besides the book mentioned above) where I can find that information, I'd be very grateful for a reference.

Comment: Did you see the book referenced in the Wikipedia article, [*The life and letters of James Macpherson, containing a particular account of his famous quarrel with Dr. Johnson...*](https://archive.org/details/lifeandlettersof00saunuoft)? I didn't read it but I assume it can give you a pretty good idea.

Comment: See pages 212-213. "He was absent about two years; but only a portion of that time was spent at Pensecola, for he soon quarrelled with his chief, and departed on a visit to some of the other provinces. After a tour in the West Indies he returned in 1766."

Comment: @BrianZ I am reading _The life and letters of James Macpherson, containing a particular account of his famous quarrel with Dr. Johnson_. It's available online for free. The author almost completely skips over Macpherson's trip to America, which is why I ask. That book really focuses on whether Macpherson wrote or really translated Ossian's poems.

Comment: @eje211 that seems worth of an edit and elaboration in the question

Comment: According to https://www.google.com/books/edition/The_Letters_of_David_Hume/yFvR0ZE6vZ8C?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22he+will+probably+depart+for+Florida+with+governor+Johnstone%22&pg=PA403&printsec=frontcover,  the in a letter of 6 October 1763 the philosopher Hume made the snide and un-PC suggestion that "I would advise him to travel among the Chikisaws or Cherokees, in order to tame him or civilize him."

Comment: @kimchilover This was a time in the life of Macpherson when he was particularly difficult to be around. He was apparently much more pleasant before and after that time. This sounds like a joke more than anything else. A joke that is extremely offensive by today's standards, but a joke nevertheless.